# Clang links to different locations when referring a templated static variable from multiple compilation units

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

In the attempt to compile an existing (GCC developed) code base with Clang, we're facing this interesting problem. As a result the **Clang-compiled executable creates multiple instances of some singletons**. Not sure if our usage and understanding is in accordance with the standard, or if GCC an/or Clang or the C++ standard library and toolchain on Linux actually have a problem.

- we're using a factory to create singleton instances
- the actual creation is delegated to a policy template
- at some places, we're using a variation of the singleton factory, where the actual type of the singleton can be configured at the *definition* site, without the necessity to reveal that concrete type to the client accessing the singleton. The client just knows the interface type
- the problem shows up when referring to the "same" static variable through an inlined function used from **different compilation units**

The following is an excerpt, omitting any locking, lifecycle issues, initialisation and clean-up

---

**File-1**: `clang-static-init.hpp`

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

namespace test {

  /* === Layer-1: a singleton factory based on a templated static variable === */

  template<typename I                     ///< Interface of the product type
          ,template <class> class Fac     ///< Policy: actual factory to create the instance
          >
  struct Holder
    {
      static I* instance;

      I&
      get()
        {
          if (!instance)
            {
              cout << "Singleton Factory: invoke Fabrication ---> address of static instance variable: "<<&instance<<"...\n";

              instance = Fac<I>::create();
            }
          return *instance;
        }
    };

  /**
   * allocate storage for the per-type shared
   * (static) variable to hold the singleton instance
   */
  template<typename I
          ,template <class> class F
          >
  I* Holder<I,F>::instance;




  template<typename C>
  struct Factory
    {
      static C*
      create()
        {
          return new C();
        }
    };





  /* === Layer-2: configurable product type === */

  template<typename I>
  struct Adapter
    {
      typedef I* FactoryFunction (void);

      static FactoryFunction* factoryFunction;


      template<typename C>
      static I*
      concreteFactoryFunction()
        {
          return static_cast<I*> (Factory<C>::create());
        }


      template<typename X>
      struct AdaptedConfigurableFactory
        {
          static X*
          create()
            {
              return (*factoryFunction)();
            }
        };
    };

  /** storage for the per-type shared function pointer to the concrete factory */
  template<typename I>
  typename Adapter<I>::FactoryFunction*  Adapter<I>::factoryFunction;



  template<typename C>
  struct TypeInfo { };



  /**
   * Singleton factory with the ability to configure the actual product type C
   * only at the \em definition site. Users get to see only the interface type T
   */
  template<typename T>
  struct ConfigurableHolder
    : Holder<T, Adapter<T>::template AdaptedConfigurableFactory>
    {
      /** define the actual product type */
      template<typename C>
      ConfigurableHolder (TypeInfo<C>)
        {
          Adapter<T>::factoryFunction = &Adapter<T>::template concreteFactoryFunction<C>;
        }
    };





  /* === Actual usage: Test case fabricating Subject instances === */

  struct Subject
    {
      static int creationCount;

      Subject();

    };

  typedef ConfigurableHolder<Subject> AccessPoint;

  /** singleton factory instance */
  extern AccessPoint fab;


  Subject& fabricate();

} // namespace test
```

---

**File-2**: `clang-static-init-1.cpp`

```
#include "clang-static-init.hpp"


test::Subject&
localFunction()
{
  return test::fab.get();
}


int
main (int, char**)
  {
    cout <<  "\nStart Testcase: invoking two instances of the configurable singleton factory...\n\n";

    test::Subject& ref1 = test::fab.get();
    test::Subject& sub2 = test::fabricate();  ///NOTE: invoking get() from within another compilation unit reveales the problem
    test::Subject& sub3 = localFunction();

    cout << "sub1="  << &ref1
         << "\nsub2="<< &sub2
         << "\nsub3="<< &sub3
         << "\n";


    return 0;
  }
```

---

**File-3**: `clang-static-init-2.cpp`

```
#include "clang-static-init.hpp"



namespace test {


  int Subject::creationCount = 0;

  Subject::Subject()
    {
      ++creationCount;
      std::cout << "Subject("<<creationCount<<")\n";
    }



  namespace {
      TypeInfo<Subject> shall_build_a_Subject_instance;
  }

  /**
   * instance of the singleton factory
   * @note especially for this example we're using just \em one
   *       shared instance of the factory.
   *       Yet still, two (inlined) calls to the get() function might
   *       access different addresses for the embedded singleton instance
   */
  AccessPoint fab(shall_build_a_Subject_instance);


  Subject&
  fabricate()
  {
    return fab.get();
  }


} // namespace test
```

### notable points

- we're using only a single instance of the AccessPoint
- yet still, **different compilation units** using the (inlined) function `Holder<T,F>::get()`, will **see different locations** for the static variable `instance`
- while the actual ctor call to `ConfigurableHolder` is templated with the concrete type of the singleton to create, this specific type info is *erased*; it should not bear any relevance to the type of `Adapter` or `ConfigurableHolder`
- if this understanding is correct, all usages of `get()` should see the same type of `Holder` and thus the same location of the static variable embedded in `Holder`
- but in fact the Clang compiled executable invokes the factory again for `sub2`, which is called from aonther compilation unit, while `sub1` and `sub3` share the same singleton instance as expected

Interestingly, the symbol table of an executable built with Clang-3.0 shows this static variable has been linked twice (the behaviour is the same when using Clang-3.2)

```
10: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS research/clang-static-init-1.cpp
11: 0000000000400cd0    11 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 global constructors keyed to a
12: 0000000000400b70   114 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 test::Holder<test::Subject, test::Adapter<test::Subject>::AdaptedConfigurableFactory>::get()
13: 00000000004027e0     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   28 test::Holder<test::Subject, test::Adapter<test::Subject>::AdaptedConfigurableFactory>::instance
14: 00000000004027d8     1 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   28 std::__ioinit
15: 0000000000400b10    62 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 __cxx_global_var_init
16: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS research/clang-static-init-2.cpp
17: 00000000004010e8     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   17 GCC_except_table9
18: 0000000000400e60    16 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 global constructors keyed to a
19: 00000000004027f9     1 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   28 test::(anonymous namespace)::shall_build_a_Subject_instance
20: 0000000000400de0   114 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 test::Holder<test::Subject, test::Adapter<test::Subject>::AdaptedConfigurableFactory>::get()
21: 0000000000402800     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   28 test::Holder<test::Subject, test::Adapter<test::Subject>::AdaptedConfigurableFactory>::instance
```

...while the relevant section of a GCC-4.7.2 compiled executable reads as expected

```
44: 0000000000400b8c    16 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 localFunction()
45: 00000000004026dc     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   28 test::fab
46: 0000000000400c96    86 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   14 test::Holder<test::Subject, test::Adapter<test::Subject>::AdaptedConfigurableFactory>::get()
47: 00000000004026e0   272 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   28 std::cout
48: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(st
49: 0000000000400d4b    16 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 test::fabricate()
50: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(void const*)
51: 00000000004026d0     8 OBJECT  UNIQUE DEFAULT   28 test::Holder<test::Subject, test::Adapter<test::Subject>::AdaptedConfigurableFactory>::instance
52: 0000000000400cec    15 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   14 test::Adapter<test::Subject>::AdaptedConfigurableFactory<test::Subject>::create()
53: 00000000004026c8     8 OBJECT  UNIQUE DEFAULT   28 test::Adapter<test::Subject>::factoryFunction
```

We're using Debian/stable 64bit (GCC-4.7 and Clang-3.0) and Debian/testing 32bit (Clang-3.2) to build

Comment: did you possibly manage to resolve the issue? I am experiencing similar problems with simple static instance in inline function (not templated). It seems that more than one instance is created (I am not sure whether per compilation unit or thread). Problem is resolved as soon as I turn function from inline to standalone.

Comment: Also problem is resolved, when switching from clang to gcc 4.6.

Comment: IMHO this problem looks like a very insidious compiler bug. But I haven't verified that it is there in the recent CLang version. Should probably open a bug report.

Comment: Anyway, I resolved it in our project by refactoring the whole situation away :)   -- And you are right: only Clang is affected. All the GCC versions we tested are fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to declare your singleton template class extern, and explicitly instantiate the singleton in a single compilation unit.

If your compilation units are in separate (shared) libraries, then Clang is behaving this way simply because it can.

When your code is compiled, the compiler instantiates the singleton template every time it is fully specified. At link time, all but one instantiation are discarded. But what happens if you have shared libraries in your project, and there are several link-times? Each shared object will have one instantiation of the template. GCC ensures that there will be only one surviving template instantiation in the final executable (maybe using [vague linkage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html)?), but evidently Clang does not.

Comment: agreed when dealing with shared libs. But in this case, we're doing a plain flat static link into one executable. Clang handles this correct in the standard case, but fails to detect and remove the spurious instances in the case here, where they become the same type through type erasure. I can't see any excuse why the Clang linker should *not* be able to catch and resolve that situation in the correct way.